# Decorators Zend Framework PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-decorators

I have a label and i want to change it's color:
so i'm doing this:
i have my form class in zend:

```
$this->addElement('text','name',array('label' => 'Name Event'));
$this->getElement("name")
        ->addDecorator("EditLabel");
```

and here is my decorator:

```
class OrarLib_Form_Decorator_EditLabel extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract
{

protected $html = '<div class = "label"> %s </div>';
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
}

public function render($content)
{
    $label = $this->getElement()->getLabel();
    return sprintf($this->html, $label, $content);
}
}
```

And the problem is that my textbox disappear when i use this decorator.
I'm using Zend framework.
I'm not so good, what i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to concate **$content** like this:

```
class OrarLib_Form_Decorator_EditLabel extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract
{

    protected $html = '<div class = "label"> %s </div>';
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
    }

    public function render($content)
    {
        $label = $this->getElement()->getLabel();
        $markup = sprintf($this->html, $label);

        $placement = $this->getPlacement();
        $separator = $this->getSeparator();

        switch ($placement) {
            case self::PREPEND:
                return $markup . $separator . $content;
            case self::APPEND:
            default:
                return $content . $separator . $markup;
        }
    }
}
```

Now try this:

```
$this->getElement("name")->addDecorator(array('EditLabel', array('placement' => 'append'));
```

If you want to know more check out this:

[Layering Decorators](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.form.decorators.layering.html)

Comment: the problem was here:
protected $html = '<div class = "label"> %s </div>';
and solved:
protected $html = '<div class = "label"> %s </div> %s';

Comment: Yeah you can do it that way too.